# Fantasy novel circa 1986-89 fantasy novel with a He-Man type (with an axe?) on a bright blue cover

Tags: story-identification, books

This was my favorite fantasy book as a kid.

The details I remember:

- Circa 1986-89.
- Not a well known title or part of a series
- Bright blue cover with the title in yellow
- The title was short, perhaps the character's name
- Solo He-Man type on the cover. He may have an axe. You see him knees or waist up, if I recall correctly.
- Not Young Adult. I believe there was sex in it

Comment: I'd suggest Robert Adams' "Bili the Axe", but that was part of a series.  There have been a number of covers and they otherwise fit the description pretty well.

Comment: So what was the story? If it was your favourite you should remember that.

Comment: For many of us, the cover is the *least* memorable part of a book.  Please give us a little more to go on.  Character names?  Basic storyline?  One scene that you remember?  Something.....

Comment: Maybe *The Unforsaken Hiero* by Sterling Lanier:  http://www.castaliahouse.com/the-forsaken-sequel-the-unforsaken-hiero/ ?